# Plotting NetCDF File using R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I download this [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z85e5rp95y0pgau/20150123_prof.nc?dl=0) from the Argo website.
When I tried to open it in ArcGIS 10, it produced only one set of LAT/LONG but I know there should be more than that.

I tried using R.

```
 library (ncdf4)
 nc_open("E:\\Python\\20150123_prof.nc")
```

So I opened it. But, I do not know how to proceed because I do not know how to plot this in R. I want to get the sea surface temperature of all points during the date I downloaded and interpolate them. Has anyone get an experience on this in R?

EDIT:

[image: This was the result of the code.] This was the result of the code.

Comment: Argo data is tricky, it's essentially an arbitrary vertical ribbon through the ocean, a raster in time (or displacement) and depth, the lon/lat is merely the horizontal part of the float's track. Is that really what you want? You mention sst and there are easy to use synoptic map data of that, which these Argo data do inform - maybe that's what you really want? Fwiw a 
rough work in progress for Argo in R https://github.com/mdsumner/rargo/blob/master/data-raw/rargo.R

Comment: @mdsumner: i edited the question to reflect the results of the code.

Comment: @mdsumner: I wanted to plot the Argo SST in horizontal plane.